# What should be subject line of email to inform that "i will be on leave on monday"

Tags: phrase-usage

What should be the subject of the email to inform to the team mates that i will be taking off on monday.

The following usages are proposed over here http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/114146-How-to-say-i-will-be-on-leave

```
'I am off work on Monday.'
'I'm not at work on Monday.'
'I have a holiday on Monday.'
```

But how to inform that without using **I** in the sentense.

(P.S Please feel free to correct the grammatical or better usage of english in the description of the post)

Comment: Please use capital letters where required.

Comment: "I" is the most significant part of what you want to "inform" -- it should not dropped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Taking off Monday"
"Out of office Monday"
"Taking a holiday Monday"
"See you Tuesday"

Comment: "Taking off Monday" or "Taking off on Monday"

Comment: Well, there's this thing about those who would snicker at the *off on* and people get a little uptight on a site like this. But yeah, *Taking off on Monday* was my first pass at that option.

Answer (score 0):

"Please consider my sick leave for coming Monday"

Comment: Why should Please be used, this is just information, also it is not a sick leave. I dont want to give the reason for taking off.

Comment: I think Arill thought your email was to be a request to your manager, not a notice to others after leave was approved. You didn't specify which it was in your question.